# как поместить в значении INPUT VALUE ответ запроса SQL QUERY

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поместить в значении INPUT VALUE ответ запроса SQL QUERY, на тойже странице , с помощью PHP.

```
<input type="text" id="prName" name="prName" style="color:black;" size="25">
```

запрос должен происходить внутри JAVASCRIPT ниже 
javascript c php :

```
var prodNumber = '123ABC456BGR'; // create variable with product number

document.getElementById('prName').value = "<?php

    $servername = "?????????";
    $username = "???????";
    $password = "?????";
    $dbname = "????";
    $phpvar = '"+prodNumber+"';




    // Create connection
    $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM unitslist WHERE Part_Number = '".$phpvar."'";

    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, $sql));

    $myStr = $result['Product_Name'];

    echo $myStr;


    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>"
```

Comment: При формировании текста страницы в php кто вам мешает данные подставить `value="<php echo $myStr ?>"`?

Comment: Архитектура не особо отвечает бест практис, сегодня так не пишут. Если не было бы javascript - то отделяли бы данные от шаблона но вставляли бы сразу в страницу. А раз у вас js - то нужно отдельно писать писать бекенд, отдельно делать ajax-запрос из фронта, результат писать в поле.

Comment: Я сделал изменения , добавил обращение с запросом в отдельном файле и отправляю ответ из JAVASCRIPT в INPUT HTML , но почемуто не получается увидеть результат. Пожалуста подскажите в чем моя ошбка.

Comment: document.getElementById('prName').value = "<?php $phpvar = '"+prodNumber+"'; include 'includes/uQuery.php'; echo $row['Product_Name']; ?>";

Comment: В HTML я принимаю вот так

Comment: <input type="text" id="prName" name="prName" style="color:black;" size="25" />